# Import specific json value in google spreadsheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import some facebook data into spreadsheets.

The request

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{user id}?fields=name&access_token=1{my token}
```

Gets me

```
{
   "name": "user",
   "id": "numeric id"
}
```

When I import it to spreadsheets with:

```
=IMPORTDATA(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{user id}?access_token={my token}
)
```

On the cells, I get `{"name": "user"` in one cell and `"id": "numeric id"` in another. But I only need the "name" value, How can I target just that value, in only one cell as I have no use for the second value.

Comment: Willing to do some coding?

Comment: you will need to know basic javascript and give it  a try with Google Apps Script. but you wont be able to use a custom function, and you will use urlFetchApp.

Comment: you could also use only spreadsheet functions without javascript, for example by multiple "split" calls to extract the part you want. give it a try and post your attempts and whats not working.  see TEXT functions: https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only one cell from the imported range, which happens to be its upper left corner, the `array_constrain` function can help:

```
=array_constrain(importdata("..."), 1, 1)
```

Generally, the 2nd and 3rd arguments of `array_constrain` determine how many rows and how many columns you want to keep.

You can also get rid of "name": at the beginning by using the text processing functions such as `left`, `right`, `regexreplace`, etc. For example, wrapping the previous formula in

```
=regexreplace( ... , "^\S+: |""", "")
```

will get rid of "name": and of the quote marks around the name.